# unable to align the search bar on the right side of the page

Tags: html, alignment

I want to align the `search bar` on the extreme right of the page. To do this,I wrote the following :

```
<form method="get" action="#">
    <input type="search" name="q" style="text-align:right" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't align the search bar on the right. Why is that ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="#" style="float:right">
```

Although, you should not use inline styling. Try to use external styling as much as possible.

What `float` does is move the affected element to one side of the screen. All the following elements will align themselves horizontally with the floated element.

Let's say we have 2 elements like this.

```
|| Element1 ||
|| Element2 ||
```

If I apply `float:left` on `Element1`, then the output will look like this.

```
|| Element1 | Element2 ||
```

If I apply `float:right` instead, then the output will be reversed.

```
|| Element2 | Element1 ||
```

In a nutshell, `float` does exactly what it says. It floats an element to the edge of the screen, and makes it the edge for the following elements.

PS : I wrote the edge of the screen for simplicity's sake. You can apply `float` in a hierarchical fashion as well. In that case, the edge of the parent element becomes the edge to align with.

Comment: can you please explain this `float` property

Comment: Modified my answer to explain `float`. :)

Comment: If you want to input more characters without overflowing, you can use the `size` attribute of `input`, else you might want to style the input using `width` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align` does just that, it aligns the text in an element to the right. In the case of an input box, it places the cursor to the right of the input field. You want to `float` the input box to the right, which places the input box to the far right of its parent element (in this case the form):

HTML

```
<form method="get" action="#">
    <input placeholder="Search" type="search" name="q" id="search-box" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
form{
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
    padding:5px 5px 0;
}
#search-box{
    float:right;
}
```

Here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpQfD/)**